# Why aren't my sub nested items saving in dragged position?

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, react-dnd, react-beautiful-dnd

I have taken a sandbox from the react beautiful github issue feed on nested objects from version 4 and trying to have it work in the latest version 13.  It seems like the reason it isn't working is due to some updates between dnd and react.

**Here's the original**: https://codesandbox.io/s/5v2yvpjn7n?file=/index.js

**Here is my updated version with hooks instead of comps**: https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-breeze-77k4v?file=/src/serviceCommandUnit.js

I also attempted to take the old one without hooks, assuming maybe that may be an issue, but that attempt has the same issues.  **The parents can switch but not the children**: https://codesandbox.io/s/nested-dnd-across-parent-forked-ujfwb?file=/index.js

Any insights to help on why the subitems will not save their places?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the ParseInt()

All I had to do was remove it.  Unsure what the conflict was but looks like React and Dnd had many updates since that didn't require that anymore.